# HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 Got Wet during Hurricane Irma, Hard Drive still good, can I just plug to a new identical server

Tags: raid, hp-proliant

HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 got wet during Hurricane Irma, 2 hard drive configured as RAID 1 (Mirrored) are still good. Already ordered replacement, identical specs with the old one, Can I just simply plug in the 2 hard drive to the identical server and will the new server just boot up with the old hard drives?

Answer (score 11):

The RAID configuration information is stored on the hard drives.

I would recommend plugging the hard drives back in to the same ports as they were plugged in to. Lastly, before proceeding to boot make sure your BIOS is configured to use and boot the RAID adapter and go in to the RAID configuration utility and make sure it recognizes your RAID 1 volume.

You shouldn't have any trouble.

However, whatever you do, do not try to initialize a RAID array or proceed to do anything that might try to rebuild the array if for some reason you are not seeing a healthy RAID volume right away.

Comment: This solutions seems to work, I just plug the old hard drives to the new server in the correct order and it boot up just fine to Windows....

Thanks so much!

Comment: @LeoLumacang Please mark it as an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does / did the wet server have a smart array or hba? Because that will affect what you need to do to put them into the new server.

Smart arrays in the pcie or LOM slot hold a raid Configuration for the disks where a hba would just pass through to the hard disks.

Comment: I believe the wet server has a smart array card which also got damage...Also another difference I see on the new server is the processor speed, the speed of the wet server is 2.4Ghz while the new one delivered is only 2.1Ghz....Apart from that everything remains the same....

So what is the proper approach to get the new server up and running...

The new server arrive already. I do not want to touch it yet before confirming the best approach....